# Odd behavior with insertAfter() on select dropdown. On page load, it's inserting multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image][image]I am running into a weird issue where I am displaying a message when a user selects an option on a dropdown and then reloading the page. When the user selects the option initially, it works/shows fine, but when you reload it it seems the div with the message is getting displayed multiple times. Here is my code block with the change function and the div in question. The initial state of it is set to display:none. I tried multiple things to no avail. Thank you. I attaching a screen shot of the HTML, due to the Select it's far too much to post here. Hope it helps

```
    var $desiredProposal = $('#am_oie_string_desired_proposal');
    var $displayAutoInventory = $('input[name=oie_string_display_auto_inventory]');
    var $autoInventoryWebAddress = $('#am_oie_string_auto_inventory_web_address');

  $desiredProposal.change(function() {
    var desProp = $desiredProposal.val();
    if (desProp.match(/auto/gi)) {
        $displayAutoInventory.closest('.field').show();

    } else {
        $displayAutoInventory[0].checked = false;
        $displayAutoInventory[1].checked = false;
        $displayAutoInventory.closest('.field').hide();
    }

    //Cannabis Selection with message -- this is what's not working correctly
    if (desProp.match(/cannabis/gi)) {
        $( "<div class='msg'>Note: Upon approval of this campaign order, a more intricate audit process will be done to ensure that the campaign will be approved to run.</div>" ).insertAfter($desiredProposal);
        $('.msg').show();
    }
     else {
        $('.msg').remove();
        $('.msg').hide();
    }
   $displayAutoInventory.change();
 });

$desiredProposal.change();


 // HTML
```

Comment: Can you show us options in the select that match the `/cannabis/gi`?

Comment: @AntonijaŠimić thanks, that's the only option (the one shown)